# wordpress plugin error handling

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, custom-field, errors

I am looking for a way to handle errors for a custom post type with its own custom fields. This is all part of a plugin I'm writing, however, after extensive research the only way I found is through sessions (or similar) and show it on the next page, (in which case it would save the changes).

Is there any other way of handling errors and preventing WordPress from saving the post type if something is wrong? If so how? I figured WP_Error class would work, but without luck.

If anyone can help, that would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of errors do want to catch? Some concrete examples?

Comment: For example, one of the custom fields allows to add a link (separate from the content body), however, the link is required, and if it hasn't been filled out, it shouldn't save, instead, it shows an error saying it's required. If I can achieve this, I should be able to do the rest too.

Answer (score 3):

WordPress have [`WP_Error`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Error) class for checking WordPress errors and error messages since version 2.1.0. WordPress use object of `WP_Error` class for reporting error from several WP function. However, we can use this object in plugin or theme to handle error within WordPress. This class containing verious useful method for managing error.

All methods

```
<?php
//Creating instance of error class
$error = new WP_Error( 'not_found', 'Page Not Found', 'Page Data' );

//Add new error to object
$error->add( 'not_match', 'Field Not Match' );

//Return all error codes from object
$data = $error->get_error_codes();
print_r( $data );
//Output: Array ( [0] => not_found [1] => not_match )

//Return first error code
echo $error->get_error_code();
//Output: not_found

//Return all error message
$data = $error->get_error_messages();
print_r( $data );
//Output: Array ( [0] => Page Not Found [1] => Field Not Match )

//Return error message by error code
$data = $error->get_error_messages( 'not_match' );
print_r( $data );
//Output: Array ( [0] => Field Not Match )

//Return first error message if no code are given
echo $error->get_error_message();
//Output: Page Not Found

//Return first error message for given error code
echo $error->get_error_message( 'not_match' );
//Output: Field Not Match

//Return first error data
echo $error->get_error_data();
//Output: Page Data

//Return error data from error code.
echo $error->get_error_data( 'not_found' );
//Output: Page Data

//add error data to error code
//syntex: add_data( $data, $code );
$error->add_data( 'Some data', 'not_match' );
echo $error->get_error_data( 'not_match' );
//Output: Some data

//Check whether variable is a WordPress Error.
//return bool True, if WP_Error. False, if not WP_Error.
$data = is_wp_error( $error );
var_dump( $data );
//Output: bool(true)
```

Source and hint: more background on [this post](http://khaledsaikat.com/wordpress-error-handling-with-wp_error-class/)

Comment: Would this prevent a post being saved?

Comment: no, its only messages on top of Admin. You can add or change the default messages. But if you prevent any doings, you must check for this, the best way it I think about an capability object; which you can add to different or each role.

Comment: I really need it to prevent to save anything rather than just change the default message. Not quite sure what you mean with the capabilities bit?

Comment: capabilities are objects; like 'manage_options'. You can create custom objects and ask for this; see [this codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap).

Comment: I already have custom capabilities added to administrator (and to a custom roles). But how would I prevent the saving if something is wrong?

Comment: You can ask for this capabilities with if ( current_user_can( 'your_object' ) )

Comment: The capabilities and that have already been set up and it all works, however, what I am trying to do is check if the fields a user has filled out is valid or not, and if it's invalid input, then it gives an error and doesn't save the post.

Comment: if the field an custom field; use the settings API from WP; it is an default field form WP, use an filterm, if it have or use jQuery for check the inputs of users.